# tensorboard : No graph definition files were found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I had a neural network model which i tried to visualise through Tensorboard. The code worked but the Tensorboard graph did not pick up any values. So i went back and tried a simple code for tensorboard to see what is the issue.

Here is the simple code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.add(1, 2,)
b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
c = tf.add(4, 5,)
d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
f = tf.div(c, 6,)
g = tf.add(b, d)
h = tf.multiply(g, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(h))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(h))
    writer.close()
```

When i launch this through `tensorboard --logdir path/to/logs` the graph launches with no results. See the snapshot. [Tensorboard output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbKt4.png)

**No graph definition files were found.**

Debugging with with `tensorboard --inspect --logdir DIRECTORY_PATH` i see this.

`Event statistics for ...- 
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars -
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -`

Any idea where i am going wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `writer.flush()` need to be called before `writer.close()`

Comment: Did that. Still no results.

Comment: I tested your code, it actually created graph with start tensorboard with command: `tensorboard --logdir=./output/ `, what's your version of your tf ?

Comment: Ok. i didnt give the directory name. Works now. Thank you.